# Explanation for why append/3 produces infinite number of solutions in these cases

Tags: list, prolog, append, infinite

I'm having trouble understanding this question about Prolog. The question is as follows:

> Select all of the following goals that have an infinite number of solutions.

And here are the possible answers:

```
append([a,b,c,d], Y, Z)
append(X, Y, X)
append(X, [a,b,c,d], Z)
append(X, Y, [a,b,c,d])
```

Apparently the correct answers are 2 and 3, but I don't get why 1 isn't also correct - wouldn't there be infinite possibilities for `Z` and hence also `Y`? Also, why would 2 be correct, since the first argument and the third argument ("the result") are identical? Sounds like `Y` could just be `[]`.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`append(X, Y, X)` can only be true of `Y == []` (that's a "theorem for free" à la Wadler) but under that constraint, `X` can be any of infinite set of possibilities:

SWI-Prolog finds out about `Y == []` and is noncommittal about the content of the `X` list, giving it only as a list of unbound variables:

```
?- append(X,Y,X).
X = Y, Y = [] ;   % alternative writing of X = [], Y = []
X = [_6696],
Y = [] ;
X = [_6696, _7824],
Y = [] ;
X = [_6696, _7824, _8952],
Y = [] ;
X = [_6696, _7824, _8952, _10080],
Y = [] ;
X = [_6696, _7824, _8952, _10080, _11208],
Y = [] 
...
```

And you are correct that `append([a,b,c,d], Y, Z)` should be listed as admitting an infinite number of solutions.

Interestingly, SWI-Prolog does not enumerate templates / lists of placeholder variables / candidates in this case but spits out what is essentially a rewrite of the constraint `append([a,b,c,d], Y, Z)`, i.e. it behaves more theorem-proverish than in case 1:

```
?- append([a,b,c,d],Y,Z).
Z = [a, b, c, d|Y].
```

(That's a Prolog ambiguity: When does it enumerate and when not? If there **were** a Prolog notation for *"list of N values of unspecified content, N an integer between 0 and +oo"* such a notation could be used as output of `append(X,Y,X)` instead.)

The alternative, not chosen here, would be:

```
?- append([a,b,c,d],Y,Z).
Y = [], 
Z = [a,b,c,d] ;
Y = [_1], 
Z = [a,b,c,d,_1] ;
Y = [_1,_2], 
Z = [a,b,c,d,_1,_2] ;
...
```

Are there any Prologs that do the above? There might be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand the first bit now, but the second is still really confusing me. Do we simply have to accept that it's ambiguous or is there some other way to look at it?

Comment: @Veins Well, the ambiguity lies in Prolog's behaviour, but that's just the way it is. `Z = [a, b, c, d|Y].` is a template for an infinite number of solutions, but in compressed form. It's just the way the implementation works.

Comment: For the well-known "standard" `append` no Prolog has a license to enumerate more than one different solution for `append([a, b, c, d], Y, Z)`. However you could change the nonrecursive clause to `append([], Ys, Ys) :- list(Ys).` where `list([]). list([_|Xs]) :- list(Xs).`, and *then* you would get the enumeration of answers you list. Anyway, I wrote an alternative answer that tries to explain that there is no ambiguity if we don't use the word "solution" for two different concepts.

Comment: @Isabelle Newbie: "no Prolog has a license to enumerate more than one different solution" ... (do you mean "answer"?) But why not? Because it is specified that way in the ISO standard (maybe?).

Comment: It occurred to me that Prolog might lie because it is deficient in type information Consider `append([a,b,c,d],Y,Z).`. For `Z = [a, b, c, d|Y].` we can evidently have `Y=foo, Z=[a,b,c,d|foo]` (for example), so `Z` is not a list and I would expect `append([a,b,c,d],foo,[a, b, c, d|foo]).` to throw a domain exception. But actually no! At least in SWI Prolog, it says "true" so it deals in "other things than lists" ... oh wow oh wow.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I believe `append/3` is not part of the ISO standard, and there are prolog processors without it (not saying they were claiming to be ISO compliant)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer you can look at `listing(append)`, SWI uses the common definition where the "base" clause is simply `append([], A, A)`. This only has one solution, and as you observed, nothing to give any "type information". And with this definition the Prolog implementation isn't allowed to make up random terms on its own.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be precise in talking about Prolog, it's necessary to distinguish between (at least) *answers* and *solutions* to a query. An *answer* is a procedural notion, it is a substitution of variables produced by Prolog every time a query succeeds. A *solution* is a substitution of variables under which a query succeeds. Every answer substitution is a solution, but this does not make these notions synonymous.

Consider this predicate:

```
foo(a).
foo(a).
```

This has two answers (which happen to look the same):

```
?- foo(X).
X = a ;
X = a.
```

It has a single solution: Only the substitution `X = a` makes it succeed, and Prolog can even prove this:

```
?- X = a, foo(X).
X = a ;
X = a.

?- dif(X, a), foo(X).
false.
```

In this case there were more answers than solutions. The opposite is also possible:

```
bar(f(_X)).
```

Here the query `bar(T)` has a single answer, but more than one solution (in fact, infinitely many):

```
?- bar(T).
T = f(_708).

?- T = f(1), bar(T).
T = f(1).

?- T = f(2), bar(T).
T = f(2).
```

So now let's look at the first query from the question:

```
?- append([a, b, c, d], Y, Z).
Z = [a, b, c, d|Y].
```

With the definitions from above, this has a single *answer*. But as you point out, we can substitute infinitely many different values for the variables, getting infinitely many *solutions*, for example:

```
?- Y = [1], append([a, b, c, d], Y, Z).
Y = [1],
Z = [a, b, c, d, 1].

?- Y = [1, 2], append([a, b, c, d], Y, Z).
Y = [1, 2],
Z = [a, b, c, d, 1, 2].
```

Now, the bad news is that your teacher doesn't seem to be using the same convention as I am using here. Using the terms defined above, the teacher was asking about *answers*, while you are thinking in terms of *solutions*. It would be interesting to know if they understand this distinction, and what terms they use for these distinct notions. If they really meant *answers*, then they are correct that this query does not have infinitely many. If they really meant *solutions*, then you are correct that it does have infinitely many of those.

As for the second query:

```
?- append(X, Y, X).
X = Y, Y = [] ;
X = [_818],
Y = [] ;
X = [_818, _824],
Y = [] ;
X = [_818, _824, _830],
Y = [] .
```

You're right that `Y` can only be `[]`, but that still leaves an infinite number of *solutions* for `X`. And here Prolog also produces infinitely many *answers* describing those solutions.

Comment: Excellent food for thought.